# How can I compare or verify Button.Background to a hexadecimal color in Silverlight using C# code programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, silverlight-5.0

**Updated**:
How can I compare or verify Button.Background to a hexadecimal color such as {#FF008F06} etc.. in Silverlight application using C# code programmatically?

Comment: Curious to ask why do you need this?

Comment: In the testcase i need to verify the button color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Background property is of type [Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so it can be a `SolidColorBrush` or a `GradientBrush` and so on.

I think you need to distinguish between the various types and perform the correct comparison.

For example:

```
if(Button.Background is SolidColorBrush)
{
    bool isRed = ((SolidColorBrush)Button.Background).Color == Colors.Red;
}
else if (Button.Background is GradientBrush)
{
    ...
}
```

To compare a to a specific hexadecimal color:

```
bool flag = ((SolidColorBrush)Button.Background).Color == 
                           (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF008F06");
```

Comment: How can i compare the Button.Background to a hexadecimal colour value such as {#FF008F06} etc

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Test Assert

```
var Greenish = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
Assert.AreEqual(Greenish.Color, ((SolidColorBrush)Button.backGround)).Color;
```

Comment: Can i have with `Assert` statement in better way?

Comment: Clearly you have not tested the answer you suggest, you can't even switch on that type.

Comment: "need to check first" does in my mind clearly state that i think this could be valid BUT that I need to check wether it is valid, but thank you again for noting it can't be done the way i proposed it first; i will edit the answer.

Comment: On top of that you assume that two different SolidColorBrush objects with the same color are equal. They are not.

Comment: Then again, i think your constructive skills just went below zero

Comment: Removing downvote since the answer is now correct (apart from a typo'd parenthesis). To be constructive for a third time, I'll point out that there is no need to create a brush to test against, check the other answer to see this.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas to point this out to me, seems i had a blue wednesday :s; +1 for the "there is no need to create a brush to test against"